# How to make input fields readonly up on submit and keep the form data in the field?

Tags: php, mysql

Can you all help me with the approach I need to take once the user has submitted his data, I want those certain fields to be read-only permanently for that user upon submit.

So far I am able to save the data to MYSQL DB on submit and the below code also keeps the data in the field. But on refresh, the data in the form field disappears. How do I solve this? Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

`<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lname">Last Name*</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"  placeholder="Last 
      Name" name="lastname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lastname'])) {echo 
              htmlentities($_POST['lastname']);}?>" autocomplete="nope" required/>`

[image] it should look like this each time the user login.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple just add readonly into your input filed.

`<input type='text' value='Test' id='test1' readonly>`

Comment: Thanks for the help, if I make it read-only I cant enter anything into the field.

Answer (score 1):

do one thing in your database table keep a field for flag and then set a value for it like Active or Deactive then at the time of submitting the data check the user is exist or not if exist then do disable to the input fields like

SELECT * FROM users WHERE `status` LIKE 'Active';

execute this query accordingly u set the input fields readonly

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You might need javascript to do the trick. The trigger being clicking the submit button and change the readonly attribute to true as shown below.

jQuery <1.9

```
$('#relevantId').attr('readonly', true);
```

jQuery 1.9+

```
$('#relevantId').prop('readonly', true);
```

Comment: unfortunately, with this approach, it does not let me enter anything into that field

Comment: The readonly attribute should be set to true only if the submit is clicked. That is why I mentioned it should be set to readonly only after the click is triggered.

Comment: Now it worked for me, thank you so much. But how to keep the data in the same field upon refresh as well?

Comment: You may use sessions / javascript / php to get the relevant values then feed it to the input box using the value attribute.